# Access window created by electron application from native C code

Tags: c++, c, electron, x11, cairo

We have an electron application and wish to access the window created by that application from Cairo in native C code. Following is the code on electron side to get the window id

```
  const handle = windowObject.getNativeWindowHandle();
  const windowId = handle.readUInt32LE(0);  // We are currently targetting x86 on linux
```

Now, we have the following code in C to create the surface:

```
Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
int screen = DefaultScreen(d);
Drawable da = windowIdPassedFromElectronApp; 

// Drawable da = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, x, y, 0, 0, 0);
// The code in the comment above works - but that creates a new window,
// we wish to use the window created by electron application

XSelectInput(d, da, ButtonPressMask | KeyPressMask);
XMapWindow(d, da);
cairo_surface_t* sfc = cairo_xlib_surface_create(d, da, DefaultVisual(d, screen), x, y);
```

Above code throws the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
Serial number of failed request:  7
Current serial number in output stream:  9
```

How can we ensure that the C code can be securely given permission to draw onto the window created by electron application? Would some alternative architecture work for our use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to solve this by creating a child window with parent as the window passed by the electron application. Sample code:

```
Drawable da = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, windowIdPassedFromElectronApp, offsetX, offsetY, sizeX, sizeY, 0, 0, 0);
```